# how can i get Data Lifecycle Manager log and send result to slack

Tags: amazon-ec2, snapshot, dlm

i want to get dlm log and send result to slack
like this

[datetime]

instance id : ~~~~
snapshot status : Completed

instance id : ~~~~
snapshot status : Completed

instance id : ~~~~
snapshot status : Completed

if you know please tell me how to get dlm result